# Смена активностей

Tags: java, android, activity

В приложении 2 активности. Первая активность стартовая. С первой на вторую можно попасть нажав кнопку, а с второй на первую нажав back. Вторая активность с использованием SurfaceView(простая рисовалка).
  Как лучше сделать перемещение между ними так, что бы рисунок сохранялся во второй активности при переходе в меню? Знаю про сохранение в SharedPreferences, но нет ли более изящного решения?

Код первой активности:

```
@Override
public void functionUp(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DrawActivity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity) mContext).finish();
}
```

Код второй активности:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы финишируете активности после ухода с них? Это необходимо в вашем приложении?

Comment: @Werder Если не финишировать их, то они будут открывать одна поверх другой, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Фрагменты не пробовали использовать?

Comment: Нет, вы просто будете двигаться по стеку активити, и в таком случае во второй активности не нужно переопределять метод onBackPressed(), кнопка и так вернет вас назад на первую активность (финишировать ее не нужно)

Comment: В каком виде можно получить картинку с SurfaceView? В виде Bitmap?

Comment: Да, картинка у меня хранится в переменной bitmap

Comment: Но проблема в том, что когда я выхожу со второй активности нажатием back, метод onSaveInstanceState не срабатывает, и bitmap не добавляется в bundle

Comment: Почитайте про методы сохранения здесь - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana - написано подробно и понятно